# Bootstrap - input box within a col-xs-6 container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
            Search
            <span>
                <input style="width:100%" type="text" />
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
            <span>...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I ensure the above input box is 100% the size of the container minus the text "Search" ?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/c9kprdqh/

UPDATE: I'd like "Search [...]" to be 100% of the col-xs-6 container. So in other words, I need the "[...]" to be the remainder of the container (minus the Search text) but I'm not sure how to do this.

UPDATE: I'd like the above to be on one line. So "Search [...]" should be one line.

Comment: Add a jsfiddle code example to your post. You will get a quick responses by doing so.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c9kprdqh/

Comment: You mean `container-fluid`?  Or the `span`?

Comment: I'd like "Search [........................................]" to be 100% of the col-xs-6 container. So in other words, I need the "[.................]" to be the remainder of the container (minus the Search text) but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/c9kprdqh/2/)

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem.
Here is how i would do it.

```
<span>Search</span>
<div id="rest">
    <input></input>
</div>
```

```
span {
  float:left;
}
//rest = a div containing the input element
#rest {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}
//Finally the input
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why the `input` element displays on a new line in the OP's example, and why it would have to be wrapped in a `div` container to display inline.

Comment: 1. Why op's input is on a new line. `width:100%` this will take up the full width of the container that is: col-xs-6. And since search takes some space it wil be forced to go on a new line. 

2. Why it has to be wrapped in a div..... wel... um.. wow did some reading on this. NOW the default type of input = text and the width is not supported by an input: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#text-(type=text)-state-and-search-state-(type=search) so width: auto;  does not work. but setting it to a fixed size does

Comment: Just on a side note, the OP does not have to use "width=100%" AFAIK: the input takes up 100% of the container on a new line without it.  I think Charles should accept this as the answer.